# remove certain things using preg_replace

Tags: php, preg-replace

My string:

```
Hi there!<div><br></div><img src="../images/Character Green.png"><div><br></div><div>Yes hello</div>
```

I just want the words to show - in this case, it would be `**Hi there!**' and '**Yes hello**'

I think I need to use preg_replace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case you can use strip_tags function

```
echo strip_tags($s); // Hi there!Yes hello
```

or a little complicated to divide words by `<br>` tag

```
$res = array_filter(explode('<br>', strip_tags($s, '<br>')));
echo implode(' ', $res); // Hi there! Yes hello
```

Comment: i tried your first answer, but it now displays no space in between 'there!' and 'yes'

Comment: with your second answer, it puts a br tag under neath hi there, but i need them to be on the same row

Comment: thank you for it now displays 'array' at the beginning